# useEffect hook is turning into infinite loop even when the dependency is not changing all the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Below is my component in reactjs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { loginUserAction } from '../actions/authenticationActions';
import { setCookie } from '../utils/cookies';

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [isSuccess, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const login = useSelector(state => state.login.response);

  console.log(login);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (login !== undefined) {
      setSuccess(login.success);
      setMessage(login.message);

      if (isSuccess) {
        setCookie('token', login.token, 1);
      }
    }
  }, [login]);

  const onHandleLogin = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const email = event.target.email.value;
    const password = event.target.password.value;

    dispatch(loginUserAction({
      email, password,
    }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Login Page</h3>
      {!isSuccess ? <div>{message}</div> : <Redirect to='dashboard' />}
      <form onSubmit={onHandleLogin}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      Don't have account? <Link to='register'>Register here</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

It logs user in. As you can see I am using hooks. When I `console.log` login from `useSelector` hook, it console's the updated state. Then the `useEffect` hook gets called. But the problem is the login is not updating all the time. But still `useEffect` goes into a loop. What am I missing and how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Below is my reducer

```
import * as types from '../actions';

export default function(state = [], action) {
  const response = action.response;

  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, response };
    case types.LOGIN_USER_ERROR:
      return { ...state, response };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here is the action.

```
import * as types from './index';

export const loginUserAction = (user) => {
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN_USER,
    user
  }
};
```

Comment: I can't see why this may be happening. Do you mind sharing the reducer and the actionCreator ?

Comment: @ShravanDhar I just updated the question with reducer and action code.

Comment: `types.LOGIN_USER` is not defined in the reducer

Comment: @ShravanDhar that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you share any codesandbox link ?

Comment: Could You please share the result on `console.log(login)`. If login is an `Object` the `useEffect` might not be able to tell when it changes and if the reference changes on every render, it can cause the loop

Comment: @Davit yes it is an object.

Comment: Please try to use only the `message` (assuming it is a string) as a dependency and modify the code accordingly for a brief moment. I am not sure if `useSelector` keeps the reference unchanged, but this might help...

Comment: @Davit I already tried that it is still in loop. The problem is that useEffect hook is keep getting called but the condition inside the useEffect i.e. `if (login !== undefined) {` does not get true. So the setMessage and setSuccess does not get executed all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to destructure the object to make the comparison easier

```
  const {message = '', success = false, token = ''} = useSelector(state => state.login.response || {}); //should prevent the error, of response is undefined

  console.log(message, success);

  useEffect(() => {
    //there are other condition options like maybe if(message?.length)
    if (message) {
      setMessage(message);
    }

    // Can move setSuccess out of the if, to setSuccess even when it is falsy
    if (success) { //note that using isSuccess here might not work cause the state might be the old one still
        setSuccess(success)
        setCookie('token', token, 1);
      }
  }, [message, success, token]); //having scalar values (string and boolean) will prevent the loop.
```

Comment: The problem is that `state.login.response` does not always contain success and message. When there is an error in login then it returns these properties but if the user is authenticated successfully then it returns a token only. How can I handle that situation? And sometimes it can contain an array of objects.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case the restructured `{messge, success}` will be assigned `undefined` to both of them, meaning that the condition in `if` will not be met. Is it okay, sound good to me?

Comment: Now it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined` error on `const {message, success} = useSelector(state => state.login.response);` line.

Comment: With that update it return `TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined` error. This time it is for message.

Comment: Edited the answer, please try adding the `|| {}` part.
Also please consider reviewing the conditions, because You said that if auth is successful, then only `token` is returned, but in that case, the condition `if(success)` will not be met because `success` will be undefined... Also, note that the whole `response` turns out to be undefined sometimes. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That seems to be working now but one use case is that `state.login.response ` may also contain array of objects. How can I handle that case with this approach?

Comment: That might cause problems with this particular approach because You will be unable to destructure the `response`  if it is an `array` and not an `object`.  At the moment I can't say anything particularly helpful, but surely more conditions will do the trick, but You might have to rollback the restructuring part, at least partially.  If You are the one setting the `response` I suggest doing some preprocessing of data, and set it maybe in different object, properties, to make things less complicated. Sorry if it wasn't much helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (login && !isSuccess) { // Here
      setSuccess(login.success);
      setMessage(login.message);

      if (isSuccess) {
        setCookie('token', login.token, 1);
      }
    }
```

Try to add this and see if this works

---

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    user: null,
    isUserLogged: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        userAuthStart(state, action) {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null,
                user: null,
                isUserLogged: false,
            };
        },
        userAuthSuccess(state, { payload }) {
            return { ...state, loading: false, user: payload, isUserLogged: true };
        },
        userAuthFail(state, { payload }) {
            return { ...state, loading: false, error: payload, isUserLogged: false };
        },
        userLogout(state) {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: null,
                user: null,
                isUserLogged: false,
            };
        },
    },
});

export const {
    userAuthStart,
    userAuthSuccess,
    userAuthFail,
    userLogout,
} = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

> I use `@reduxjs/toolkit` for redux.

You can declare and update state of isUserLogged or something to true if user is logged successfully. Then, you can use useSelector to use it inside components.

### How to use

```
const { isUserLogged } = useSelector(state => state.auth)
```

Comment: Then try to store isSuccess or isUserLogged inside redux and from there use this everywhere else?

Comment: How can I store it in redux? What do you exactly mean?

Comment: Please notice: I use redux toolkit

Comment: I have no idea how can I use that reducer. Can you show me?